# I have recently started learning 'tkinter' in python and my code returns a: NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Tags: user-interface, import, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

topFrame = Frame(window)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm finding it quite frustrating but that's probably because I'm new :D

Comment: This is in python 3.5 btw. Can anyone help?

Comment: Runs perfectly on my machine... Doesn't the import give you any error?

Comment: Post your entire stack please. In a readable fashion.

Comment: did you name your file "tkinter.py"?

Comment: If you do the import as `import tkinter as tk`, then `print(tk)` should print (on Windows) something like `<module 'tkinter' from 'C:\\Programs\\Python36\\lib\\tkinter\\__init__.py'>`.  In this case, `tkinter` is obviously the stdlib module.  Bryan's suspicion, which I share, is that for your it will not be the stdlib module.

Comment: I'm using pyCharm edu but it works fine on python IDLE so I'll just use that. Thanks for the quick replies!